# Formatting a Core Plot graph using a CSS file

Tags: css, cocoa, formatting, core-plot

I'd like to give users of my application the ability to format plots using something like a CSS file. The application is in Cocoa and I'm using the graphing framework Core Plot. Does anyone know of a relatively simple way of achieving this or will I have to manually parse the CSS file and the convert the CSS into formatting information for the plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use CorePlot, I think you're stuck with CSS parsing. Is SVG in a UIWebView an option for you though?

Comment: My application runs on a Mac so I don't think UIWebView is an option.

Comment: Just a WebKit `WebView` then?